# Proving dual convex cone property

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-programming

I am trying to prove the following statement

**If $C_1 \subset C_2$ then $C_2^{*} \subset C_1^{*}$**

Here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are convex cones in $\mathbb{R^m}$.
The dual of a convex cone is defined as $C^{*} = \{ y : xy \leq 0 \text{ for all } x \in C  \}$.

Is this a correct proof?

Suppose $y \notin C_1^{*}$, then $xy > 0$ for all $x \in C_1$. On the other hand if $x \in C_1$ then $x \in C_2$. Hence we have $y \notin C_2^{*}$. By contraposition, if $y \in C_2^{*}$ then $y \in C_1^{*}$. Therefore $C_2^{*} \subset C_1^{*}$

Comment: You should have said "Suppose $y \notin C_1^{*}$, then $xy>0$ for some $x\in C_1$"

Comment: Yes except replace "for all x in C_1$ with "there exists x in C_1"

Comment: Thanks. I guess if we do that change, then the rest of proof is not correct anymore, no?

Comment: No it is completely correct after that one change.  I would replace x with x_0 or something just to emphasize it being a specific value.